# Why does Latex stick to itself?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science

I was launching a HAB and noticed powder on the balloon. I looked it up and found it was magnesium silicate (I thought it was hydrophobic to keep the balloon from getting wet and getting weighed down in clouds). However, the internet told me it stopped the balloon from sticking to itself? I also noted that moisture makes the sticking worse? Is it the case that somehow water makes latex sticky (why?) and magnesium silicate locks out moisture, or something else? How exactly does latex stick to itself?